# I need to create a clickable image, within the bounds of the picture. Then I need the picture to switch between those in a folder

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have been struggling with this problem for a little while, i can get the picture to switch with a general active listener but cannot select a zone for the clickable area to allow for the switch. I was hoping to create a rectangle with bounds that would allow me to have a clickable area to change the pictures with. i attempted this but am unsure how to set an action listener to work in a specific area of a jpanel. any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
public class drawPictures {
Random random = new Random();
int one = random.nextInt(1200)+1;
int two = random.nextInt(600)+1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new drawPictures();
}

public drawPictures() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new ImageViewPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class ImageViewPane extends JPanel {

    private ImagePane imagePane;
    private File[] fileList;
    private int currentIndex = -1;

    public ImageViewPane() {

        fileList = new File("/Di/rec/tory").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.isFile();
            }
        });

        imagePane = new ImagePane();
        imagePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(one, two, 100, 100);
        if (bounds.contains((e).getPoint())){
          // Image was clicked...
          currentIndex++;
          if (currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
              currentIndex = 0;
          }
          nextImage();
            }

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(imagePane);

        nextImage();
            }});}

    public void nextImage() {
        if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex < 0 || currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
            Image image = null;
            /*
                Because I don't know the contents of the folder, this is a little
                more complicated then it really needs to be.

                If you know the file is an image, you can simply use ImageIO.read(file)
            */
            while (image == null && currentIndex < fileList.length) {
                System.out.println("Loading next image: " + currentIndex);
                try {
                    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fileList[currentIndex]);
                    if (iis != null) {
                        Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
                        if (imageReaders != null && imageReaders.hasNext()) {
                            ImageReader imageReader = imageReaders.next();
                            imageReader.setInput(iis);
                            image = imageReader.read(0);
                        } else {
                            currentIndex++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        currentIndex++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    currentIndex++;
                }
            }
            imagePane.setImage(image);
            invalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

    private Image image;
    private JLabel label;

    public ImagePane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        label = new JLabel("No image available");
        add(label);
    }

    public void setImage(Image value) {``
        if (image != value) {
            image = value;
            label.setVisible(image == null);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this)+140, image.getHeight(this)+200);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int x = (width - image.getWidth(this)) / 2 -500 + one;
            int y = (height - image.getHeight(this)) / 2- 300 + two;
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);


        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the obvious things...

You never actually add `ImagePane` to anything (to start with, you try to add it after it's been clicked, but how does it get clicked if it's not added to anything?)

```
//...
public ImageViewPane() {
    //...
    imagePane = new ImagePane();
    imagePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //...
        }
    });

    // And... nothing
}
```

There's a lot going on in your `MouseListener` which really doesn't need to be there...

```
imagePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(one, two, 100, 100);
        if (bounds.contains((e).getPoint())) {
            // Image was clicked...
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
            nextImage();
        }

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(imagePane);

        nextImage();
    }
});
```

Your calling `nextImage` at least once, if not twice.  Once if the user clicks inside your invsible box and once at the end of the method.  You're also incrementing the `currentIndex` value, despite the fact that `nextImage` does this anyway.  You also seem to trying to add `imagePane` to the container...again...

This could be simplified down to...

```
imagePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(one, two, 100, 100);
        if (bounds.contains((e).getPoint())) {
            // Image was clicked...
            nextImage();
        }
    }
});
```

Next, your `nextImage` method...

```
public void nextImage() {
    if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex < 0 || currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        Image image = null;
        /*
        Because I don't know the contents of the folder, this is a little
        more complicated then it really needs to be.

        If you know the file is an image, you can simply use ImageIO.read(file)
         */
        while (image == null && currentIndex < fileList.length) {
            System.out.println("Loading next image: " + currentIndex);
            try {
                ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(fileList[currentIndex]);
                if (iis != null) {
                    Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
                    if (imageReaders != null && imageReaders.hasNext()) {
                        ImageReader imageReader = imageReaders.next();
                        imageReader.setInput(iis);
                        image = imageReader.read(0);
                    } else {
                        currentIndex++;
                    }
                } else {
                    currentIndex++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }
        imagePane.setImage(image);
        invalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Okay, this is actually not to bad, the "fluff" around reading the image could be simplified by filtering out those files which you know aren't files

```
fileList = new File("/a/directory/somewhere").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isFile()
                && (pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")
                || pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".bmp")
                || pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")
                || pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif"));
    }
});
```

Let's just pretend we live in a world where extensions actually meaning something.  You could equally try and read the image here and discard it if it's not an image, but that's woefully time consuming...

This allows use to make `nextImage` more like...

```
public void nextImage() {
    if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex < 0 || currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        try {
            Image image = ImageIO.read(fileList[currentIndex]);
            imagePane.setImage(image);
            invalidate();
            repaint();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, personally, I'd have the `File`s in a `List`, each time a `File` failed to produce an `Image`, I'd remove it from the `List`, but that's me

Add finally, you should also add...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1200, 600);
}
```

to your `ImageViewPane` class, this will allow you to pack the frame around it (I kept losing my "magic" square during testing because the window was to small)

I'm not entirely sure what this is trying to do...

```
int x = (width - image.getWidth(this)) / 2 - 500 + one;
int y = (height - image.getHeight(this)) / 2 - 300 + two;
```

But, something like...

```
int x = one + ((100 - image.getWidth(this)) / 2);
int y = two + ((100 - image.getHeight(this)) / 2);
```

will allow you to center the image within the "magic" square...

And finally, because a bunch of out of context code is hard to put back into place...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawPictures {

    Random random = new Random();
    int one = random.nextInt(1200) + 1;
    int two = random.nextInt(600) + 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawPictures();
    }

    public DrawPictures() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImageViewPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageViewPane extends JPanel {

        private ImagePane imagePane;
        private File[] fileList;
        private int currentIndex = -1;

        public ImageViewPane() {

            fileList = new File("...").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return pathname.isFile()
                            && (pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")
                            || pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".bmp")
                            || pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")
                            || pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif"));
                }
            });

            imagePane = new ImagePane() {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.drawRect(one, two, 100, 100);
                }

            };
            imagePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(one, two, 100, 100);
                    if (bounds.contains((e).getPoint())) {
                        // Image was clicked...
                        nextImage();
                    }
                }
            });
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(imagePane);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(1200, 600);
        }

        public void nextImage() {
            if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
                currentIndex++;
                if (currentIndex < 0 || currentIndex >= fileList.length) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                try {
                    Image image = ImageIO.read(fileList[currentIndex]);
                    imagePane.setImage(image);
                    invalidate();
                    repaint();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private Image image;
        private JLabel label;

        public ImagePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("No image available");
            add(label);
        }

        public void setImage(Image value) {
            if (image != value) {
                image = value;
                label.setVisible(image == null);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this) + 140, image.getHeight(this) + 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                int width = getWidth();
                int height = getHeight();
                int x = one + ((100 - image.getWidth(this)) / 2);
                int y = two + ((100 - image.getHeight(this)) / 2);
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);

            }
        }
    }
}
```